# JExcel: How to extract values from excel cell that are computed using formula?

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I am using `Jexcelapi` for read of`.xls` excel worksheets. The problem is to read the cell value that is generated by computing formula.

How to read the numeric cell value or string cell value from excel through java implementation?